# Why is 'The Second World War' not taking replace of 'World War 2'?

Tags: javascript

Why is 'The Second World War' not taking replace of 'World War 2' ?

```
var wha = prompt("What is?");
for (var i = 1; i < wha.length; i++) {
  if (wha.slice(i,i+12) ==="World War 2" ) {
    wha =wha.slice(0,1) + "The Second World War" + wha.slice(i +12);
  }
}
alert (wha);
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please?

Comment: Because that's what you programmed! Try using `.indexOf` instead of a loop.

Comment: Put `console.log(wha.slice(i, i+12));` after `for (var i = 1; i < wha.length; i++) {` and you'll see why your script isn't working

Comment: Why not `string.replace('World War 2','The Second World War')`? See [*String.prototype.replace*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because i value u start with 1 instead of 0 and instead of wha.slice(0,1) you should give wha.slice(0,1) and u have use i+11 instead of i+12 in both if as well as append.

```
var wha = prompt("What is?");
for (var i = 0; i < wha.length; i++) {      
  if (wha.slice(i,i+11) ==="World War 2" ) {
    wha =  wha.slice(0,i) + "The Second World War" + wha.slice(i +11);
  }
}
alert (wha);
```

Comment: Thanks Rajavel D , Your code is working well . I have found desired result

Comment: I have changed the i value as 0 instead of 1 and removed that wha.slice(0,1)

Comment: this code is wrong. I try to put "new World War 2", and this code replaces the text "new" as well

Comment: Whenever it finds 'World War 2'it replaces The Second World War

Answer (score 0):

If i got the question correctly

are you looking for this

```
var wha = prompt("What is?");
for (var i = 0; i < wha.length; i++) {
if (wha.slice(i,i+12) ==="World War 2" ) {
wha =wha.slice(0,0) + "The Second World War" + wha.slice(i +12);
}
}
alert (wha);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jghD9/

Comment: @user3693429, if this helped you don't forgot to accept this answer by clicking the green tick. :)

Comment: @user3693429, your mistakes: in for loop it should i=0 ,you wrote i=1 and wha.slice(0,0) or wha.slice(1,1)  not wha.slice(0,1)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code (only small changes that I made):

```
 var wha = prompt("What is?");
    for (var i = 0; i < wha.length; i++) {
      if (wha.slice(i,i+12) ==="World War 2" ) {
        wha =wha.slice(0,i) + "The Second World War" + wha.slice(i +12);
      }
    }
    alert (wha);
```

Comment: What have you changed ?Plese let me know

Comment: var i = 0; and wha.slice(0,i)

Answer (score 0):

The String's slice method takes 2 arguments,
   
- one is "start" => Required. The position where to begin the extraction. First character is at position 0
   
- another is "end" => Optional. The position (up to, but not including) where to end the extraction, If omitted, slice() selects all characters from the start-position to the end of the string

So the ending position should be plus 11, not 12
Check out the code:

```js
   var wha = prompt("What is?");
    for (var i = 0; i < wha.length; i++) {
        if (wha.slice(i,i+11) === "World War 2" ) {
            wha =wha.slice(0,i) + "The Second World War" + wha.slice(i +11);
        }
    }
    alert (wha);
```

The "The Second World War" should takes place of "World War 2" in the input sentence now